# Error when using /i switch in conjunction with if command running within for loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm getting the following error:

```
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~xI"==".URL" (start /B "%%I" "%PROGNAME%\Internet Expl
orer\iexplore.exe" "%%I")


For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

my code is this:

```
for %%I in (%CD%\Startup\*) do IF /i "%~xI"==".URL" (start /B "%%I" "%PROGNAME%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "%%I") ELSE (start /B "%%I" "%%I")
```

I'm trying to place .url files in the same directory as other extensions, and run one command for the url files, and a seperate command for the other files to force the url files to open in seperate browser windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%I in ("%CD%\Startup\*") do IF /i "%%~xI"==".URL" (start /B "%%~I" "%PROGNAME%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "%%~I") ELSE (start /B "%%~I" "%%~I")
```

Comment: In case it's hard to see, the `"%~xI"` should be `"%%~xI"` and please `accept` Endoro's answer if it solves your problem.